# How to get an Ansible check to run only once in a playbook?

Tags: git, ansible

As a safeguard against using an outdated playbook, I'd like to ensure that I have an updated copy of the git checkout before Ansible is allowed to modify anything on the servers.

This is how I've attempted to do it. This action is located in a file included by all play books:

```
- name: Ensure local git repository is up-to-date
  local_action: git pull
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'Updating' in command_result.stdout"
```

The problem is that this command is run once for each node Ansible connects to, instead of only once for each playbook run. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Updated

When I fist wrote my answer (2014-02-27), Ansible had no built-in support for running a task *only once* per playbook, *not* once per affected host that the playbook was run on.  However, as [tlo writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34526387/126273), support for this was introduced with [`run_once: true`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) in Ansible version 1.7.0 (released on 2014-08-06).  With this feature, the example task definition from the question should be changed to

```
- name: Ensure local git repository is up-to-date
  local_action: git pull
  run_once: true
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'Updating' in command_result.stdout"
```

to accomplish what is asked for.

## Original Answer

*[The following answer was my suggested solution for the particular problem of making sure that the local git branch is updated before Ansible runs the tasks of a playbook.]*

I wrote the following Ansible callback plugin that will avoid playbook execution if the current git branch is out of sync (is either behind or has diverged) with the remote branch.  To use it, place the following code in a file like `callback_plugins/require_updated_git_branch.py` in your top-level Ansible playbook directory:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import re
import subprocess
import sys

from ansible.callbacks import display, banner


class CallbackModule(object):
    """Makes Ansible require that the current git branch is up to date.
    """
    env_var_name = 'IGNORE_OUTDATED_GIT_BRANCH'

    msg = 'OUTDATED GIT BRANCH: Your git branch is out of sync with the ' \
          'remote branch.  Please update your branch (git pull) before ' \
          'continuing, or skip this test by setting the environment ' \
          'variable {0}=yes.'.format(env_var_name)

    out_of_sync_re = re.compile(r'Your branch (is behind|and .* have diverged)',
                                re.MULTILINE)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.getenv(self.env_var_name, 'no') == 'yes':
            self.disabled = True

    def playbook_on_start(self):
        subprocess.call(['git', 'fetch'])

        if self.out_of_sync_re.search(subprocess.check_output([
            'git', 'status', '--untracked-files=no'])):
            display(banner(self.msg), color='bright purple')
            sys.exit(1)
```

For example, when the local branch is behind the remote branch, the command `ansible-playbook site.yml` halts early with the following output:

```
 __________________________________________________________
/ OUTDATED GIT BRANCH: Your git branch is out of sync with \
| the remote branch. Please update your branch (git pull)  |
| before continuing, or skip this test by setting the      |
\ environment variable IGNORE_OUTDATED_GIT_BRANCH=yes.     /
 ----------------------------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

And, as the cow suggests, to turn off this check you can run the command like:

```sh
$ IGNORE_OUTDATED_GIT_BRANCH=yes ansible-playbook site.yml
```

This solution does not solve the general problem of avoiding to run any Ansible task more than once regardless of the number of hosts involved, but it ensures that outdated playbooks are not executed, and it handles the concern that you mentioned regarding my [alias-based suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22071183/126273).

Comment: Technically, `run_once` is per play, not per playbook. If you playbook contains multiple plays that e.g. all include the same role which contains a task with `run_once`, that task will run once _per each play_.

Answer (score 19):

Since version 1.7 of Ansible you can use `run_once: true` [to only run a task one time and only on one host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once).